# How can I add a folder to the root of the default user?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, users, user-profile

There is a program we have that needs to be set up after the user signs in. This change is the same for everyone and only needs to be done once. We are trying to present that app in Citrix and are having a small issue.

I am trying to get this file to populate when the local profile is being created.

```
C:\users\[username]\.folder\.settings\properties.ini
```

Since this only needs to happen on a few server I figured a simple way would be to use the default user profile and add that folder into it. In practice it appears this is ignored by the profile creation process.

I was curious if there was something authoritative that explains why that didn't work. Searching mostly leads to image creation and dealing with unattend.xml which is not what I am trying to do.

---

We are likely going to be using a GPO and populate the RunOnce to run a script or something similar. I am trying to avoid running a script everytime the user signs in for something that only has to happen once.

Comment: You can add files and folders using GPPs in a Windows domain environment.

Comment: @Lenniey I assumed as much. More curious why what we tried to do didn't work which I assume is by design.

Comment: No I mean: a GPP _in_ your GPO: `User Configuration -> Preferences -> Windows Settings -> Folders -> New Folder`, then use `%USERPROFILE%` or whatever you need.

Comment: I knew what you meant. Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: I suggest you consider using procmon to understand why modifying the default profile doesn't work.

Comment: I would guess that the profile creation process intentionally ignores files and directories beginning with a dot.  You could check that by experiment I suppose.  This behaviour probably isn't documented, unless you count "The only supported method for customizing the default user profile is by using the Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup\CopyProfile parameter in the Unattend.xml answer file."